# Parse "no results found for query (code 101)". Can't get object id

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I've installed the example parse server (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) on my desktop and made a simple app to test it.

My app saves an object to the server, gets the object and sets mTextView's value to the value of my object.

The problem is, when I try this code to get data from server it works:

```
    query.getInBackground("5K7N8a8Dmd", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() ...
```

(got the object id with curl)

but when I try this (to get object id w/o using curl):

```
            gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    objectId = gameScore.getObjectId();
                } else {
                    Log.e("saveInBackground", getErrorMessage(e));
                }
            }
        });

...

    query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() ...
```

it doesn't work.

logcat:

```
E/getInBackground﹕ no results found for query - code: 101
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView mTextView;
    public String objectId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .applicationId(Constants.APP_ID)
                        .server(Constants.SERVER_URL)
                        .build()
        );

        final ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("Foo1234");
        gameScore.put("score", 5000);
        gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    objectId = gameScore.getObjectId();
                } else {
                    Log.e("saveInBackground", getErrorMessage(e));
                }
            }
        });

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Foo1234");
        query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(gameScore.getInt("score")));
                } else {
                    Log.e("getInBackground", getErrorMessage(e));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public String getErrorMessage(ParseException e) {
        return e.getMessage() + " - code: " + e.getCode();
    }
}
```

---

Constants.java

```
    public class Constants {
    public static String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.14:1337/parse/";
    public static String APP_ID = "myAppId";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any value in objectId ?

Comment: @Le_Master yeah.

Log.i("objectId", objectId);  --> I/objectId﹕ wfBB0gpCkP

but can't access it outside from the done callback method

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Foo1234");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId","wfBB0gpCkP");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // row of Object Id "wfBB0gpCkP"
        } else {
            // error
        }
    }
});
```

Also change

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Foo1234");
```

to

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Foo1234");
```

See if this works.

Comment: but i don't want to hardcode the object id "wfBB0gpCkP"

Comment: Did this work? If yes, replace the hard coded value with the variable and try.

Comment: Updated the answer. Try that.

Comment: It works! but something is wrong with the 2nd line. i've changed both parameters (to ("some string",someObject)) and it was still working. i've even deleted that line and it is still working. i thought it's necessary to have object id to retrieve the value of the object? (in official docs it says: "If you have the objectId, you can retrieve the whole ParseObject using a ParseQuery...")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "background" part of `saveInBackground()`.  The save isn't complete on the line following the save.  In fact, it hasn't even begun to save.  The save isn't complete until the completion handler runs.

Consider...

```
        // code here runs **first**
        gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // code here runs **third, much later than second**
            if (e == null) {
                objectId = gameScore.getObjectId();
            } else {
                Log.e("saveInBackground", getErrorMessage(e));
            }
        }
        // code here runs **second, immediately**
```

Run  the "get" query within the completion handler of the save and you'll see that it works.  (Of course, there's not much reason to get the object since you have the handle to the object upon which you just invoked save).